# Joomla 2.5 Private Messaging

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla 2.5.7. When i am trying to select user in private message component, it shows only admin users. Registered users are not available. I want to use private messaging for registered users. Suggest me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the Private Messaging component that comes standard with Joomla, then this is only available to admins, as it's an admin component and registered users won't be able to enter the backend to check their messages.

If you are looking for a PM component, then I would highly recommend [UddeIM](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/pms/3206) which is free and also integrates with lots of other 3rd party extensions such as Kunena and Community Builder.

Just on a side note, you should update your Joomla version to 2.5.14

Hope this helps